# USB wireless mouse keeps disconnecting Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, mouse, hardware, input-devices

I have a **Logitech M705** mouse that keeps disconnecting from the computer.
I don't know how to debug this, I tried to install `hardinfo` and saw that the USB device suddenly disconnected:

[image]

It's happening randomly, any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome. It may seem off the wall but I have a Logitech wireless keyboard that uses that same unified receiver and it turned out the Bluetooth dongle was causing a problem. Might you have a Bluetooth device as well?

Comment: Hi, no, I have a USB that connects the mouse to the computer wirelessly.